# Получeние всей ветки ответов на комментарий к посту

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

При запросе [wall.getComments](https://vk.com/dev/wall.getComments) возвращаются только комментарии из основной ветки (к посту), при этом ответы на эти комментарии (которые также являются комментариями к посту) по умолчанию не возвращаются.

У того же метода есть поле *thread_items_count*, где можно указать значение от 0 до 10.

10 комментариев из побочной ветки я получаю без забот.

Но как получить больше, например, 11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там есть **comment_id** идентификатор комментария, ветку которого нужно получить, задайте идентификатор родительского комментария и получите нужные комментарии.